# Empty elements created, d3.js

Tags: d3.js

My transitions in my code are out of sync so elements write on top of each other instead of removing the elements first and then adding new elements. I think the reason for this might be because lots of empty g elements are being created and not removed. I am not sure though, my code can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/ice1/hNwUg/1/

I tried an alternative way to do what's shown on fiddle, using data.filter to avoid creating empty elements but it doesn't give any output:

```
var data = [ [[0,0],[0,1],[0,2],[0,1]], [[0,0],[0,0],[0,1],[0,1]] ];
svg.selectAll("text.data")                
  .data(data.filter(function(d){return d[0][0];}))//changing this to d[0] outputs the whole array 
  .enter()
  .append("text")
  .classed("data",true)
  .text( function(d,i) {
       return d; 
   })
  .attr("x", function(d,i) { return (i * 50) + 200; })
  .attr("y", function(d,i) { return (i * 50) + 150; })
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .attr("fill", "black"); 

svg.selectAll(".data")
  .transition()
  .delay(function(d, i, j) {       
          return i * 1000 + 1000; 
  })
  .remove();
```

Is there a better way to continuously add and remove elements, to avoid creating empty elements or is there a problem with the way I have used nested selection (code on jsfiddle)?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you want to do? The jsfiddle seems to be working just fine.

Comment: @LarsKottoff Lots of empty g elements also get created: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B9CuJXctgOrqLVk2LWV3RWtIeDA/edit?pli=1 I know its due to the nested selection so I was trying to find an alternative way to display and remove elements because in my visualisation (not examples above), my transitions are out of sync and I was thinking it might be due to removing all the g elements. I am not sure though so thought I would find another way. Is using data.filter not a suitable way?

Comment: I can't seem to find any other reason why the transitions are taking place in the wrong order :/

Comment: If you want to display only a small subset of your data, then you should use that to drive the visualisation instead of the entire data. The transitions in your jsfiddle seem to be taking place in exactly the order you have specified.

Comment: I think that might be the problem, I am using the entire data when each time I am only displaying a subset of it. This might be causing delays in removing elements as it has to remove all the elements, empty ones too. Thanks Lars! I will change that code :D Also, just wondering what's wrong with the way I have used data.filter? I was trying to get the same output as shown on jsfiddle.

Comment: I still don't know what you're talking about. Your jsfiddle seems to work fine -- how do you want it to be different? Or do you want to do something different from what's in the fiddle?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. The above code, I am filtering it so it will only display data[0][0] and then remove it one by one but it doesn't display anything at all atm.

Comment: I wanted to know why the code above doesn't work, why it doesn't give the same output as fiddle.

Comment: You don't need `.filter()` if you want a specific element: http://jsfiddle.net/hNwUg/2/ Does that answer your question?

Comment: Yeah that answers my question. I can't believe I forgot about that. No wonder it wasn't working! Thank you! Sorry for confusing you.

Comment: Ok great. I'll add that as an answer for reference.

Comment: Yep sure and I will accept it :) Thanks once again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your code isn't doing the same as the jsfiddle is that your `.filter()` doesn't do what you think it does. To access an individual element, you just need to index into the array, not filter it.

Example modified with your code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hNwUg/2/). All I've done is change

```
.data(data.filter(function(d){return d[0][0];}))
```

to

```
.data(data[0][0])
```